# MYSQL Workbench error : Error Code: 1364. Field 'dniAlumnos' doesn't have a default value "

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

alguno me puede ayudar con este error? Cuando intento hacer un insert en la tabla "asistencias" me salta que mi foreign key no tiene un valor default, pero no deberia ser automatico? Dejo mi codigo, gracias!

```
USE dbfinal3;
CREATE TABLE alumnos (
  dni int(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE primary key,
  apellido varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  direccion varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  curso int(2) NOT NULL,
  division varchar(5) NOT NULL,
estado varchar(35) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

  CREATE TABLE asistencias (
  idAsistencia int NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  dniAlumnos int NOT NULL,
  fecha date NOT NULL,
constraint fk_dniAlumnos foreign key (dniAlumnos) references alumnos(dni)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Dejo tambien los insert que he estado probando!

```
insert into `alumnos` (dni,apellido,nombre,direccion,curso,division,estado) values
  (40441958,'Perez','Javier','Martelli 234','3','A','Regular');

 insert into `alumnos` (dni,apellido,nombre,direccion,curso,division,estado) values
  (50987187,'Martinez','Juan','Belgrano 534','2','B','Irregular');

insert into `asistencias` (fecha) values
  ('1998-10-19')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu tabla de `asistencias` tiene dos campos requeridos forzosamente `fecha` y `dniAlumnos` (eso significa el `NOT NUll`)

Cuando ejecutas

```
insert into `asistencias` (fecha) values ('1998-10-19')
```

No estás insertando el dniAlumnos .Tendría que ser algo como

```
insert into `asistencias` (dniAlumnos, fecha) values (40441958, '1998-10-19')
```

o

```
insert into `asistencias` (dniAlumnos, fecha) values (50987187, '1998-10-19')
```

O cualquier otro dni válido de algún alumno.

Al decirte que no tiene valor de default, significa que la base de datos primero revisará el valor que elegiste, si no hay, verificará el default y como no tiene, entonces te marca el error

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por responder! Se supone que el dniAlumnos debería insertarse solo, copiando el numero de dni de la tabla "alumnos", por eso no lo ponia. De igual manera al intentar hacerlo como me dijiste me sale el siguiente error " Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". Gracias por el tiempo!

Comment: Ahhh! Ya entendi, muchas gracias por el tiempo!

Comment: No se puede insertar solo una llave foranea, ya que no sabe cuál insertar. Checa bien las comas, podrías copiar y pegar la consulta que estás insertando?

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no pones el campo `dni` de la tabla alumnos como `auto_increment`.
Lo correcto sería:

```
CREATE TABLE alumnos (
  dni int(20) auto_increment NOT NULL UNIQUE primary key,
  apellido varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  direccion varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  curso int(2) NOT NULL,
  division varchar(5) NOT NULL,
estado varchar(35) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por responder! Es necesario colocar el auto increment? porque se supone que el dni lo tienen que completar los usuarios, es algo como el numero de identidad de cada persona.